# Can you get UpdatePanel working with RichDataControls?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, listview

is it possible? say with the listview?

Comment: Sounds like it is working, you "inserted an item and the entire page didn't reload, the item is just added", isn't that what you want?

Comment: yes that is what i want, but when i press {edit} it reloads the page, and when i press update to update the item being edited, it also reloads the entire page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the relevant part of code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel 
    ID="upComments" runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvComments" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsComments">
```

Comment: (btw, the preferred way of updating your question is to edit the original question, not add a new answer)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`ChildrenAsTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers.aspx) attribute to `true` in order for this work as you expect.

Comment: tried that, same thing, enter page loads when i click edit or update

Comment: Post the relevant part of the code. It will make it easier to provide you with an answer.

Comment: Done, posted the relevant parts